# Replace Woocommerce 3.3 Variable Price Range with Selected Variation Price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am wondering if the Woocommerce Variable Product Price Range can be replaced once the attributes have been selected.

Essentially; I want the product price range to disappear and be replaced by the price of the specific variation the user has chosen.

You see the price range of the product before choosing a color & size:

[image: You see the price range of the product before choosing a color & size]

Once the user has made his/her choice; the range in then replaced with the price of the appropriate variation that was selected.

Here, once the user has made his/her selection; the price range is then replaced by the price of the product selected:

[image: Here, once the user has made his/her selection; the price range is then replaced by the price of the product selected.]

Any direction towards a solution would be greatly appreciated…

I know that woocommerce uses a java script template to determine and display the price of the product, but I am not sure if I can control where that price is outputed.

Related template: [`single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php)

Comment: it'll be easier to just hide Product Price Range on user click. a bit js and nothing else